# expected='obj' actual='obþ' org.apache.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream@3f49e266

Tags: java, pdf, automation, base64, pdfbox

Getting below error when trying to write a decoded byte to pdf

```
java.io.IOException: expected='obj' actual='obþ' org.apache.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream@3f49e266
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseObject(PDFParser.java:509)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:179)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:859)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:826)
    at com.stepdefinition.InternalAPISteps.i_call_the_Print_registration_api_and_save_the_pdf_data(InternalAPISteps.java:62)
    at ?.And I call the Print registration api and save the pdf data(src/test/resources/com/Configuration/ConfigurationGuestForms/Edit&PrintRegCrad/Edit_Print_RegCard_GSR_Folio_TC_001.feature:35)

Code:
        byte[] decodedBytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);
        InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(targetStream);
        document.save("C:/test.pdf");
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("C:/test.pdf"), decodedBytes);
```

Updated pdf version to 2.0.16 and tried, after updating i see this below error

```
java.io.IOException: Unknown dir object c='>' cInt=62 peek='>' peekInt=62 at offset 713
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseDirObject(BaseParser.java:966)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSArray(BaseParser.java:636)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseDirObject(BaseParser.java:879)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSDictionaryValue(BaseParser.java:154)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSDictionaryNameValuePair(BaseParser.java:283)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSDictionary(BaseParser.java:216)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseDirObject(BaseParser.java:867)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseFileObject(COSParser.java:912)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseObjectDynamically(COSParser.java:881)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseObjectDynamically(COSParser.java:801)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseDictObjects(COSParser.java:761)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.initialParse(PDFParser.java:187)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:226)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1199)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1099)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you add full stacktrace?

Comment: @VladCheremisin Added

Comment: @TilmanHausherr pdbbox-1.2.0

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Updated pdfbox to 2.0.16 and now i get this exception
Unknown dir object c='>' cInt=62 peek='>' peekInt=62 at offset 713
Full exception is in first post

Comment: Looks like am invalid pdf.

Comment: Yes. Please upload the file to a sharehoster and link to it.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem - you can shorten your code to `PDDocument.load(decodedBytes);` because the load() method can handle byte arrays, and this is much faster than using `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr the pdf is invalid , when i try to decode it online it gives junk character, the developers say its a decoded java object, so this automation will not be possible for me. Thank you for your help , got to learn a lot of things.